# How to resolve Web3 promises objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to get the account info from the Ethereum web3 functions, but it returns Promises and I don't know how to call the value inside them using Async/Await syntax!

Here is the code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');;


var accounts = async function fetchAccounts() {
let accs = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
return accs;
}; 

async function balance () {
let bal = await web3.eth.getBalance('0x398E42Da3254a22e13AbDBB4C68998BCDb3e2F1D');
    return bal;
};


 balance();
```

Result:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Then I tried:

```
 web3.eth.accounts[0];

 accounts();
```

Result:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

#### EDITED

Then I tried to implement the solution that others have flagged as a duplicate answer of the async issue but even applying the results, I still get Promise:

```
(async() => {
  try {
  let bal = await balance();
  console.log(bal);
      }
  catch (e) {
      //whatever
  }
}
)();
```

Returns:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: For your `balance` in the above, refer to `myfunc` in the answers to the linked question. `balance`, like all `async` functions, returns a promise. So you have to consume that promise (with `await` or `then`).

Comment: I tried the await as you can see in my edited part of the question, but when I apply the solution from the link you sent, I still get returned another promise. So I cannot extract the value out of it. Do you know why?

Comment: Your `async` at the end works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ucav48rt/